# markup language with formulae and html + LaTeX output

Tags: markup

I'd like to create a software manual with some kind of markup language. I need HTML and LaTeX output. The markup language must support math formulae (basic ones, including fractions). Which markup language do you suggest? I have tried asciidoc (no forumlae except for the LaTeX filter, but the output is extremely bad with LaTeX output) and textile,markdown. (no formulae?).

The input should be easy, so inserting a MathML formula is not a good option IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/formulas.html) it does support formuals?

Comment: Still not evaluated doxygen, but sphinx looks pretty much what I want: http://sphinx.pocoo.org/